# i had made one login page related to my my website using java script and that login page is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 
 document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 
}
function myFunction1()
{
 var pass1=document.getElementById('pass1').value;
 var pass2=document.getElementById('pass2').value;
 
 if(pass1==pass2)
 {
  window.alert("You have been been registered successfully");
   document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 
 }
 else
 {
 window.alert("Password is incorrect");
document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML; 
 }
 
 
 }

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<!-- <h1></h1><h1></h1><h1></h1><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet'>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<style>
 #header h1{text-align:center;font-size:40px;float:left;}
body{font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:14px; color:#333}
li,ul,body,input{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none}
#login-form{width:350px; background:#FFF; margin:0 auto; margin-top:70px; background:#f8f8f8; overflow:hidden; border-radius:7px}
.form-header{display:table; clear:both}
.form-header label{display:block; cursor:pointer; z-index:999}
.form-header li{margin:0; line-height:60px; width:175px; text-align:center; background:#eee; font-size:18px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}

/*sectiop*/
.section-out{width:700px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}
.section-out:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.section-out section{width:350px; float:left}

.login{padding:20px}
.ul-list{clear:both; display:table; width:100%}
.ul-list:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.ul-list li{ margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:12px}
.input{background:#fff; transition:all 800ms; width:247px; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-right:none; outline:none; color:#999; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; padding-left:10px; font-size:16px}
.input,.login span.icon{vertical-align:top}
.login span.icon{width:50px; transition:all 800ms; text-align:center; color:#999; height:40px; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0; background:#e8e8e8; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-left:none; font-size:16px}
.input:focus:invalid{border-color:red}
.input:focus:invalid+.icon{border-color:red}
.input:focus:valid{border-color:green}
.input:focus:valid+.icon{border-color:green}
#check,#check1{top:1px; position:relative}
.btn{border:none; outline:none; background:#0099CC; border-bottom:solid 4px #006699; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; margin:0 auto; display:block; height:40px; width:100%; padding:0 10px; border-radius:3px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF}

.social-login{padding:15px 20px; background:#f1f1f1; border-top:solid 2px #e8e8e8; text-align:right}
.social-login a{display:inline-block; height:35px; text-align:center; line-height:35px; width:35px; margin:0 3px; text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF}
.form a i.fa{line-height:35px}
.fb{background:#305891} .tw{background:#2ca8d2} .gp{background:#ce4d39} .in{background:#006699}
.remember{width:50%; display:inline-block; clear:both; font-size:14px}
.remember:nth-child(2){text-align:right}
.remember a{text-decoration:none; color:#666}

.hide{display:none}

/*swich form*/
#signup:checked~.section-out{margin-left:-350px}
#login:checked~.section-out{margin-left:0px}
#login:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(1),#signup:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(2){background:#e8e8e8}
#footer div{background-color:white}
</style>


<script>
function myFunction()
{
 
 document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 
}
function myFunction1()
{
 var pass1=document.getElementById('pass1').value;
 var pass2=document.getElementById('pass2').value;
 
 if(pass1==pass2)
 {
  window.alert("You have been been registered successfully");
   document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 
 }
 else
 {
 window.alert("Password is incorrect");
document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML; 
 }
 
 
 }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
  
          <h1 style="height:75px"><strong>DIGITAL LIBRARY</strong>
          </h1>
    <img src="images/lib3.PNG" alt="LOGO" width="170" height="140" style="float:right">
        <ul>
   </ul>
  </div>

 <div id="content">
<div id="login-form">

<input type="radio" checked id="login" name="switch" class="hide">
<input type="radio" id="signup" name="switch" class="hide">

<div>
<ul class="form-header">
<li><label for="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</label></li>
<li><label for="signup"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> REGISTER</label></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="section-out">
<section class="login-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="" id="nameform" method="get">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><span class="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="check"> <label for="check">Remember Me</label></span><span class="remember"><a href="">Forget Password</a></span></li>
<li>
<a id="id1" href="index.html" >
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" style="width:300px;height:50px;background-color:#6C7CB0;color:#F3EBEB;">Sign in</button>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign in with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="signup-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="First Name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="Last Name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Confirm Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="check1"> <label for="check1">I accept terms and conditions</label></li>
<li>
<a id="id2" href="login.html">
<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="myFunction1()" style="height:50px;width:300px;background-color:#4C0DE5">Register</button>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign up with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
   <div>   
            <marquee>
          <img src="images/animation.gif">
          
          <div style="color:blue; font-size:18px"> MADE BY:<br>
          Pallavi Agrawal <br>
          Supratim Bhattacharya<br>
          Nidhi Verma
          </div>
            
 </marquee>
 
   </div>
   <p>
   
   </p>
  </div>
 

</div>   
</body>

</html>
```

-->

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">

          <h1 style="height:75px"><strong>DIGITAL LIBRARY</strong>
          </h1>
          <img src="images/lib3.PNG" alt="LOGO" width="170" height="140" style="float:right">
        <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>

 <div id="content">
<div id="login-form">

<input type="radio" checked id="login" name="switch" class="hide">
<input type="radio" id="signup" name="switch" class="hide">

<div>
<ul class="form-header">
<li><label for="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</label></li>
<li><label for="signup"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> REGISTER</label></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="section-out">
<section class="login-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="" id="nameform" method="get">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><span class="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="check"> <label for="check">Remember Me</label></span><span class="remember"><a href="">Forget Password</a></span></li>
<li>
<a id="id1" href="index.html" >
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" style="width:300px;height:50px;background-color:#6C7CB0;color:#F3EBEB;">Sign in</button>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign in with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="signup-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="First Name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="Last Name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Confirm Password"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="check1"> <label for="check1">I accept terms and conditions</label></li>
<li>
<a id="id2" href="login.html">
<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="myFunction1()" style="height:50px;width:300px;background-color:#4C0DE5">Register</button>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign up with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
            <div>           
            <marquee>
          <img src="images/animation.gif">

          <div style="color:blue; font-size:18px"> MADE BY:<br>
          Pallavi Agrawal <br>
          Supratim Bhattacharya<br>
          Nidhi Verma
          </div>

    </marquee>

            </div>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div>


</div>          
</body>
```

Comment: can you clarify the problem you're having?

Comment: In this code a register form has been made.There are 2 fields password and confirm password in the form.I would like to show the alert dialogue box when this 2 fields matches.but it is not responding so...and thats why i want you all to debug my java script code.